# Using express-validator to validate array object value from req.body

Tags: javascript, postman, express-validator

I am trying to send an array of the object as a form-data using postman. Then validate the data using express-validate I created a function that will handle the validation process of my body.

```
validate.js
import { check, body } from "express-validator";
import { validationResult } from "express-validator";
export const addEvent = () => {
  return [
    check("name", "Name is required").notEmpty(),
    check("pricing")
      .isArray()
      .notEmpty(),
    check("pricing.*.ticketType")
      .notEmpty()
      .withMessage("Price type is required"),
    check("pricing.*.price")
      .notEmpty()
      .withMessage("Price type is required"),
    (req, res, next) => {
      let errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: "Invalid parameters",
          stack: errors.array({ onlyFirstError: true }),
        });
      } else {
        next()
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is how i test it using postman
[image: img]

but when I tested it out it returns an error

```
"message": "Cannot convert object to primitive value"
```

Comment: The check() and body() are both only can valid input body of POST call, the express-validator can't valid `form-data`. That is my investigate result.

Comment: @BenchVue when i tested it out removing the name from my form-data  `check("name", "Name is required").notEmpty(),` triggers. The error comes from validating array object data when running this block `check("pricing.*.ticketType")` the error triggers.